# Adicionar ícones externos ao Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-glyphicons

Eu baixei um template Bootstrap e estou querendo trocar uns ícones que tem nele, porém, ele já tem uma tabela de ícones que podem ser usados, gostaria de saber como faço para colocar outros ícones externos, que não necessariamente seja os que já vieram cadastrados nele.
**Icons (Glyphs: 364)** Essa é a quantidade que tem, queria adicionar outros.

```html
<div class="feature">
    <i class="icon-cloud"></i>
    <p>CLOUD CONNECTIVITY</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Esse tipo de icons funcionava bem no Bootstrap 2.x, agora com o Bootstrap 3.x usa-se
`<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></i>`

```html
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="feature">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></i>
  <p class="text-danger">CLOUD CONNECTIVITY</p>
</div>
```

Entretanto se quiseres usar outra imagem é só usar a tag `img`

```html
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="feature">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/psQDd.png" >
  <p class="text-danger">CLOUD CONNECTIVITY</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser adicionado uma nova fonte de ícones sem remover o padrão do Bootstrap (Glyphicons).

Para isso recomendo o [Fontatisc](http://fontastic.me/) ou o [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/), onde é possivel gerar fontes personalizadas com CSS já pronto.

Caso já possua os arquivos de fonte de ícones (.eot,.ttf,.sv), adicione manualmente ao CSS

**Importar fontes**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontePersonalizada';
  src: url('../fonts/FontePersonalizada.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/FontePersonalizada?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/FontePersonalizada.svg') format('svg'),
    url('../fonts/FontePersonalizada.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**Nova classe base para os elementos de ícones**

```
[class^="icone-personalizado-"]:before,
[class*=" icone-personalizado-"]:before {
  font-family: "FontePersonalizada" !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

**Ícones**

```
.icone-personalizado-cloud { content: "a"; }
```

Exemplo de utilização: `<i class='icone-personalizado-cloud'></i>`